# How do you perform a Xamarin.Forms.UITest by executing async methods in a Buttons handler?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017, xamarin.uitest

I am currently working on a application for iOS and Android in Xamarin.Forms. I am working on this project in Visual Studio 2017 on Windows 10.
This application has a UI (a View) in the PCL of it, having its markup mainly in XAML. This View (which is called LoginPage.xaml/LoginPage.xaml.cs) is very appropriate to write a UITest for it and as an intern at I want to atleast write a few UITests.

So in order to accomplish this I added a UITest project in the solution. I added NuGet NUnit2.6.4 to this project, the NuGet NUnit2TestAdapter(because according to Xamarins documentation version 3 and beyond of these NuGet packages are not supported by Xamarin.UITests.) And since I do not own a Mac, I can only test on a Android device, meaning I had to install the appropriate Android SDK and Java SDK. Hurray, the tests themselves work.

The next step was to add AutomationId to the components of the View (so I gave all my buttons, labels, views etc a AutomationId). Which I did. I even have a very simple test:

```
[Test]
    public void ShouldShowMessageOnInvalidInsertedEmailadress()
    {
        app.WaitForElement(v => v.Marked("btn_StuurMail_aid").Text("Stuur me een e-mail"));
        app.EnterText(c => c.Marked("entry_Emailadres_aid"), "a wrong emailadres");
        app.DismissKeyboard();
        app.Tap(c => c.Marked("btn_StuurMail_aid"));
        app.WaitForElement(c => c.Marked("lbl_Error_aid").Text("Dat is geen geldige e-mailadres"));
    }
```

This UITest does exactly what I want from it. Note the code app.Tap(button).
The event handler which has been assigned to this button gets tapped. This leads to getting the code in the event handler get executed. The event handler checks if the inserted e-mailadress is valid, in this case it isn't so it sends the feedback to the view. This includes setting the text of a label to 'We couldn't send you an email...'. This change occurs in C# code instead of XAML because it changes at runtime. Thus far everyhing is working like a charm.

Now it gets tricky. I made a new Test in this same file (Test.cs) in the same project (UITest). Now when I enter a valid emailadress and tap the same button like this:

```
[Test]
    public void test()
    {
        app.WaitForElement(v => v.Marked("btn_StuurMail_aid").Text("Stuur me een e-mail"));
        app.EnterText(c => c.Marked("entry_Emailadres_aid"), "johnsnow@outlook.com");
        app.DismissKeyboard();
        app.Tap(c => c.Marked("btn_StuurMail_aid"));

    }
```

the same code gets triggered. The event handler of the button which gets tapped checks if the inserted email is valid (is formatted an email should be formated). In this case it does. That's why the code to send an email to the given emailadres is triggered. This is a call to an API. This means the code needs be awaited and the event handler has to be async. The code of the event handler looks like this:

```
public async void OnSendMail(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        IsBusy = true;
        lbl_Error.IsVisible = false;
        if (InsertedEmailIsValid())
        {
            try
            {
                lbl_Mededeling.Text = "Je aanmelding wordt verwerkt.";
                await repo.RegisterUserAsync(CreateOwnUser());

                lbl_Mededeling.Text = "Er wordt een e-mail verstuurd naar het door jou opgegeven e-mailadres";
                await repo.SendMail();

                lbl_VerwijzingMail.IsVisible = true;
                btn_Activeer.IsVisible = true;
                lbl_Mededeling.Text = "Er is een mail verstuurd naar " + inputEmail;
                entry_Emailadres.IsVisible = false;
                btn_StuurMail.IsVisible = false;
                IsBusy = false;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                lbl_Mededeling.Text = "Geef ter activatie een geldig e-mailadres op.";
                lbl_Error.Text = "Deze app is niet toegankelijk voor medewerkers van de organisatie waar " +
                    "het-emailadres bij hoort.";
                lbl_Error.IsVisible = true;
                IsBusy = false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            lbl_Error.IsVisible = true;
            IsBusy = false;
        }
    }
```

repo is a class which makes the actual API-call to register and send an email to the given e-mailadres. The methods have a return type of Task and are async aswell (because they in their turn need to await the API-response).

This is where the problem occurs. Now that the code in the UITest triggers multiple method call which need to be awaited, the UI doesn't seem to be execute the code when the button is tapped by the UITest any longer. The very same code works fine and as intended both when I am debugging the UITest or when I am running the application itself either in Release and Debug.

Can someone help me out?

P.S: Sorry for the random Dutch words/sentences in the code. Those are just either names of the View-components like button-names or the feedback my app gives on the screen. You can ignore these.

Answer (score 0):

After your tap on the Send email button `app.Tap(c => c.Marked("btn_StuurMail_aid"));`, you should have some state that indicate whether the email is send successfully or have an error.

With this state, you should have some UI elements updated. So, you can call `app.WaitForElement` or `app.WaitForNoElement` to make the UITest wait until your call to send email is completed.

Comment: Could you provide some more detail on the state which can be used as an indicator?
Currently, I am updating a label's text to 'You are being registered' (in Dutch) right before I make the first asyn call in the logic like so (same code as in my question):
lbl_Mededeling.Text = "Je aanmelding wordt verwerkt.";
await repo.RegisterUserAsync(CreateOwnUser());
Afterwards, I update the same labels text right before I make the second async call in the logic: lbl_Mededeling.Text = "Er wordt een e-mail verstuurd naar het door jou opgegeven e-mailadres";
                await repo.SendMail();

Comment: (Second part of my first comment)
After the email has been sent succesfully, I make another button visible on the UI. But when I use app.WaitForElement(theNewButton), the test throws an exception: Timeout because no such element was found. I even expanded the timelimit to 2 minutes to be sure the test has enough time to execute the code to register the user and send the e-mail.

Comment: According to your description, you can call the app.WaitForElement(theNewButton). But you will need to find out why it is not possible to wait for it. Is it due to the button is not correctly set with id? Or the operation is simply takes more than 2 minutes? You can call to app.Repl() in your test code to call out a repl window for debugging purpose (to check whether can query to your button)